# Need to access Hive table using database qualifier from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am able to access the hive table from spark-shell but receiving the exception specified below while submitting it as part of the job:

```
val df = sqlContext.table("dbName.tableName")
```

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Specifying database name or other qualifiers are not allowed for temporary tables. If the table name has dots (.) in it, please quote the table name with backticks (`).;

Please let me know how can I resolve this.

Comment: Can you please explain more what you are doing? what does the dbName.tableName represent concretely? Is is a hive table?

Comment: I am just trying to access the hive table called "tableName" created under database "dbName"  and create a data frame.

Comment: You can't do that from sqlContext, you'll need to define a HiveContext for that.

Comment: Thanks.. HiveContext works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do that from sqlContext, you'll need to define a HiveContext for that as followed :

```
val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
import hiveContext.implicits._
import hiveContext.sql
```

A hive context adds support for finding tables in the MetaStore and writing queries using HiveQL. Users who do not have an existing Hive deployment can still create a HiveContext.

When not configured by the hive-site.xml, the context automatically creates metastore_db and warehouse in the current directory.

Once you have defined the HiveContext, you can express queries in HiveQL.

Comment: When I am trying to write data to hive table it throws the below error: any insights? link to original question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840897/create-a-hive-table-from-list-of-case-class-using-spark/43841115#43841115

  "diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Specifying database name or other qualifiers are not allowed for temporary tables. If the table name has dots (.) in it, please quote the table name with backticks (`).;"