# create a hive table from list of case class using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to create a hive table from the list of case class. But it does not allow to specify the database name. Below error is being thrown.

Spark Version: 1.6.2

> **Error:**     diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: mytempTable; line 1 pos 58

Please let me know the way to save the output of map method to a hive table withe same structure as case class.

**Note:** recordArray list is being populated in the map method (in getElem() method infact) for the input given

```
    object testing extends Serializable {
          var recordArray=List[Record]();
           def main(args:Array[String])
          {
          val inputpath = args(0).toString();
          val outputpath=args(1).toString();


          val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("jsonParsing")
          val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
          val sqlContext= new SQLContext(sc)
          val hsc = new HiveContext(sc)

          val input = sc.textFile(inputpath)
          //val input=sc.textFile("file:///Users/Documents/Work/data/mydata.txt")
         // input.collect().foreach(println)
         val = input.map(data=>getElem(parse(data,false))) 
   val recordRDD = sc.parallelize(recordArray)
//
     val recordDF=sqlContext.createDataFrame(recordRDD)
    recordDF.registerTempTable("mytempTable") 
     hsc.sql("create table dev_db.ingestion as select * from mytempTable")
        }

    case class Record(summary_key: String, key: String,array_name_position:Int,Parent_Level_1:String,Parent_level_2:String,Parent_Level_3:String,Parent_level_4:String,Parent_level_5:String,
            param_name_position:Integer,Array_name:String,paramname:String,paramvalue:String)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have/create a HiveContext

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
HiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc.sc());
```

Then directly save dataframe or select the columns to store as hive table

recordDF is dataframe

```
recordDF.write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("schemaName.tableName");
```

or

```
recordDF.select(recordDF.col("col1"),recordDF.col("col2"), recordDF.col("col3")) .write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("schemaName.tableName");
```

or

```
recordDF.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("dbName.tableName");
```

SaveModes are Append/Ignore/Overwrite/ErrorIfExists

I added here the definition for HiveContext from Spark Documentation,

Comment: we are using spark 1.6.1 and When I follow the above steps it throws the below error ----> 

**diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Specifying database name or other qualifiers are not allowed for temporary tables. If the table name has dots (.) in it, please quote the table name with backticks (`).; **